# SQL: How to group by with two tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, sum

I have the tables **products** and **history** and I need to group by name:

products = (**id_product**, name)

history = (**id_history**, id_product, amount)

I tried this SQL query but it isn't grouped by name:

```
SELECT
      products.name,
      sum(history.amount)
FROM history
INNER JOIN products ON history.id_product = products.id_product
GROUP BY
      products.name,
      history.amount,
      history.id_history;
```

This is the result:

[image: SQL result]

Comment: You just need to group by `products.name` - not the history fields

Comment: just remove `history.amount` and `history.id_history` from the `GROUP BY`

Comment: And if you do product LEFT JOIN history, your result will also include products without a history.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only be grouping by the attributes you need to be aggregated. In this case, you need only `products.name`.

```
SELECT
      products.name,
      sum(history.amount) AS [Amount]
FROM history
INNER JOIN products ON history.id_product = products.id_product
GROUP BY
      products.name;
```

If you need to include products without history (assuming sum should be 0 instead of `null` in this case), then you can use an `OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` to include all products:

```
SELECT
      products.name,
      COALESCE(sum(history.amount), 0) AS [Amount]
FROM history
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN products ON history.id_product = products.id_product
GROUP BY
      products.name;
```

Comment: I need the name and the amount too.

Comment: This should return 2 columns: "name" and "amount". The `SELECT` controls what is returned, The `GROUP BY` controls how the `SUM` groups its calculation.

Comment: I'd do `products left join history`, because most people find it much easier to understand `main table left join optional data` instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: I do as well @jarlh, but just used right join in this case since OP had already specified that order. It is probably first time I've done a right join in years :)

Answer (score 2):

This is no answer, but too long for a comment.

For readability's sake the product table should be first. After all it is products that we select from, plus a history sum that we can access via `[left] join history ...` followed by an aggregation, or `[left] join (<history aggregation query>)`, or a subselect in the select clause.

Another step to enhance readability is the use of alias names.

### Join the table, then aggregate

```
select p.name, coalesce(sum(h.amount), 0) as total
from products p
left join history h on h.id_product = p.id_product
group by p.name
order by p.name;
```

### Aggregate, then join

```
select p.name, coalesce(h.sum_amount, 0) as total
from products p
left join
(
  select sum(h.amount) as sum_amount
  from history 
  group by id_product
) h on h.id_product = p.id_product
order by p.name;
```

### Get the sum in the select clause

```
select
  name,
  (select sum(amount) from history h where h.id_product = p.id_product) as total
from products p
order by p.name;
```

And as you were confused on how to use `GROUP BY`, here is an explanation: `GROUP BY ___` means you want one result row per `___`. In your original query you had `GROUP BY products.name, history.amount, history.id_history` saying you wanted one result row per name, amount, and id, while you actually wanted one row per name only, i.e. `GROUP BY products.name`.